# Reversing Sort-Order of Linear Axis

Tags: angular, charts, nativescript

I am currently developing an app with a chart on it. I use Nativescript for Angular with the nativescirpt-ui-chart plugin.

The chart shows grades from 1 to 5 and right now, 5 is at the top and 1 is at the bottom. It would look better if the Y-Axis was reversed. I want the Y-Axis to show smaller values at the top and higher ones at the bottom.

Despite hours of searching the docs I haven't found a way to do reverse the order of a LinearAxis yet.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The plugin is not open source, so raising an issue at [nativescript-ui-feedback](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues) might help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to alternatives, this chart plugin has support for reverse axis: https://github.com/nativescript-community/ui-chart